# getting an answer to two decimal places using the int function

Tags: python

I am brand new to python, only a week or two into my course. Here is what I have written:

```
#prompt user for input
purchaseAmount = eval(input("please enter Purchase Amount: "))
# compute sales tax
salesTax = purchaseAmount * 0.06
# display sales tax to two decimal points
print("sales tax is", int(salesTax * 100 / 100.0))
```

and this is what it returns:

> > > please enter Purchase Amount: 197.55
> > >       sales tax is 11

My text suggest I should get the answer 11.85.

What should I change to get 2 decimal places in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [string formatting mini-language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

```
>>> salesTax = 22.2
>>> print("sales tax is %0.2f" % salesTax)
sales tax is 22.20
```

Alternatively use the newer format method

```
>>> salesTax = 22.256
>>> print("sales tax is {:.2f}".format(salesTax))
sales tax is 22.26
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float instead:

`print("sales tax is", round(float(salesTax * 100 / 100.0),2))`

This will print the value to `2` decimal places as 11.85

Answer (score 0):

You're taking `int` of the whole thing, which will always be an integer.  You need to first take the `int` and *then* divide the result of the `int` by 100.  So instead of this:

```
int(salesTax * 100 / 100.0)
```

Do this:

```
int(salesTax * 100) / 100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a minor correction. You could use float to get the exact answer with the decimal point. You will lose precision with int.

```
purchaseAmount = eval(input("please enter Purchase Amount: "))
salesTax = purchaseAmount * 0.06
# get salesTax in floating point number
salesTax = float(salesTax * 100 / 100.0)
print salesTax
-> 11.853
```